# Targeting a .NET Core 2.0.1 web project from a C# Test project based on .NET 4.7.1

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, tdd, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-4.7.1

I'm starting out with Test-Driven Development with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, but can't - however hard I've tried - make it work. I've tried trawling everywhere on the WWW to search for a solution, to no avail. So I hope that someone here will be able to help. The issue goes as follows:

I have created an ASP.NET Core web application, and a separate Test project; I'm using NUnit as the test framework (I first used xUnit but for some reason the tests disappeared and would not run). Anyway, when I try to reference my ASP.NET Core Web app from the test project, the following error shows up:

Project '..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7'.    UnitTestProject1

Does anyone have a clue about what can be wrong and how it can be fixed? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

**EDIT**

I am elaborating a little on the issue here. I try to illustrate it below. I have attached 3 images to show what I mean.

First, when I want to create a test project in Visual Studio, I go to the "Test" templates - and there I only see the templates shown in fig. 1 - there I have the possibility for selecting between different .NET versions as shown in the dropdown. Regardless of which one I selected I received the error mentioned in my earlier post.

Then, I tried using the .NET Core templates where I found 2 types of test projects: MSTest and xUnit tests (see fig. 2). MSTest is not usable in my case as it's a bit too limited for this exact application. Therefore, I tried using the xUnit test project. However, when I do that, the system complains about all sorts of libraries missing, and when looking in the "Dependencies" section in the solution explorer, all libraries are shown with a yellow "Warning" triangle on them (see fig. 3), and nothing compiles at all.

So I'm a bit stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The test project is targeting .NET Framework 4.7 and the web project targets .NET Core App 2.1.

You cannot add a reference from one to another as they are incompatible.

To solve this you should create a test project that targets netcoreapp2.1 and add a reference from it to the web project.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your answer. I had a little suspicion about that, and have tried different alternatives, but I'm still stuck. Please see my edit of the earlier question, where I have elaborated a bit with some illustrations.

Comment: Have you tried doing a dotnet restore from the command line or a package restore from Visual stdio?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both - still with the same results.

Comment: Can you share a repro solution?